# Is my proof correct about sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $\{ a_n\}_n$ is a  sequence of  real  numbers  such  that
$$
(a_{n+1}-a_n) \rightarrow a, \text{ if } \ n \rightarrow \infty.
$$
Prove that
$$
\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow a \, \text{ if } \ n \rightarrow \infty 
$$
***My  Proof***

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$  such that 
$$
| a_{n+1}-a_n-a |<\epsilon  \ \forall n \geq n_0 \Longrightarrow (a-\epsilon)<a_{n+1}-a_{n}<(a+\epsilon)
$$
Let $k=n+1$, then 
$$
(a-\epsilon)<a_k-a_{n_0}<(a+\epsilon)\\
\frac{(a-\epsilon)}{n}<\frac{a_k-a_{n_0}}{n}<\frac{(a+\epsilon)}{n} \\
(a-\epsilon)< \varliminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{n}<(a+\epsilon) \\
(a-\epsilon)< \varlimsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{n}<(a+\epsilon) \\
$$
Therefore $\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} =\varliminf_{n \to \infty} =a$ and $$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=a$$

Comment: "si" - french? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
Why ?
\varlimsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}}{m}=\varlimsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}-a_{n}}{m}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon > 0, \exists \ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\forall n > N$
$$| a_{n+1}-a_n-a |<\epsilon 
$$
Or
$$(a-\epsilon)<a_{n+1}-a_{n}<(a+\epsilon)$$
Then 
$$
(m-n)(a-\epsilon)<a_{m}-a_{n}=\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}(a_{k+1}-a_{k})<(m-n)(a+\epsilon)
$$
So
$$
(1-n/m)(a-\epsilon)<\dfrac{a_{m}-a_{n}}{m}<(1-n/m)(a+\epsilon)
$$
Take upper and lower limits for $m\to\infty$
$$
a-\epsilon\leqslant\varliminf_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}}{m}\leqslant\varlimsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}}{m}=\varlimsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}-a_{n}}{m}\leqslant(a+\epsilon)
$$
Thus 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=a
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot of math craze Perfect proof

Comment: Why?   $ \varlimsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}}{m}=\varlimsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{m}-a_{n}}{m}$

Comment: because I had an error while writing , thanks for your help Math craze

Comment: $
Why ?
\lim{m \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{m}=0
$